# Check multiple condition before login in Using auth guard

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, auth-guard

I am trying to check multiple condition to let user login. I was able implement authguard when user is logged In successfully. Not only user need validate but also need to meet the criteria to login.
Here is How I have implemented auth guard to check if user is Sign In or not.

```
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  access: boolean;
  constructor(
    private auth: AuthService,
    private router: Router,
  ) {}
  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ):
    | Observable<boolean | UrlTree>
    | Promise<boolean | UrlTree>
    | boolean
    | UrlTree {
    return this.auth.user$.pipe(
      take(1),
      map((user) => (user ? true : false)),
      tap((isLoggedIn) => {
        if (!isLoggedIn) {
          this.router.navigate(['/login']);
          return false;
        }
        return true;
      })
    );
  }
}
```

While registration user has a field called `employee` which is `boolean`. So I want to implement auth guard to login so that when user login it should meet the condition that the user credentials are valid and the user is employee
I tried Following by using following way but `empolyee` was `undefined`

```
this.auth.user$.subscribe((res) => {
  this.isEmployee = res.isEmployee;
});
if (!this.isEmployee) {
  console.log(this.isEmployee);
  this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  console.log('user is not employee');
  return false;
}
console.log('user is approved', this.isEmployee);
return true;
}
```

Comment: A subscription is not going to work there. Why not simply add it to your condition? Like: map((user) => !!user && user.isEmployee)

Comment: @MikeOne I tried using that too but it shows no changes.

Comment: this.auth.user$.subscribe((res) => {
  this.isEmployee = res.isEmployee;
});  which is this code ? You have shared your `guard` but what is this code ?

Comment: @YogendraR the code is same but I have replace pipe with this.auth.user$.subscribe((res) => { this.isEmployee = res.isEmployee; });  both of them are guard code. The above one is checking for authentication and second one is I have tried to check authentication and authorization but didn't work correctly.

Comment: what is wrong where you are using pipe ? and y using operator `take()` ?
what all info does `user$` have ?

Comment: @YogendraR while using pipe I can only check authentication but I also wanted to authorization at same time. I am using `take()` because `take(1) emits 1, completes, unsubscribes`

Comment: what abt your `user$` ? what all info does it have ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have keys `isLoggedIn`, `isEmployee` you can do following:

```
return this.auth.user$.pipe(
  map((user) => {
    if(user.isLoggedIn && user.isEmployee){
      return this.router.navigate(['login']);
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  })
);
```

There is no point of using operator `take(1)` in a guard, user can attempt any number of times to get inside a page.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to implement authentication and authorization actions at the same time in your auth-guard.

You can implement user credentials and role check on your **backend**
authentication action and avoid complications in your guard.

Or you can visit this https://www.npmjs.com/package/keycloak-angular#authguard and check how both is implemented within single auth-guard.